# git clone on git bash not working with vso git rep

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I'm trying to use Git Bash to do a `git clone` on my git repo in *Visual Studio Online*. I can do it fine through Visual Studio 2013 Editor but I'm trying to figure out how to do in Bash.

```
git clone https://myvso.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/myproj
```

I keep getting

```
fatal: https://myvso.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/myproj/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to TFS git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835212/connect-to-tfs-git-repository)

Comment: Check out the linked question - the web page of your repo should contain a _Clone_ link or button that allows you to show the URL.