# How to change git repo when connected to TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I create the project on the TFS. During creation I select usage of the git repo's.
I delete the default git repo and create 2 new repo`s for abowe project. 
Then I launch the msvs and connect to workspace. It suggested to clone the git repo for starting work. Ok, I press "clone repo" and see the following:

[image]

In the remote repo textbox present the default repo path - but as I note abowe I delete it an there are now 2 new repos. But I can`t change the remote repo path.
Why it happens? How to change it? What I must to do in the current situation?

Comment: Can you share your detailed steps? If you have two repos in the TFS, they should be both listed in the Team Explorer so that you can choose which to clone. Can you also share a screenshot for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **can't be changed** during clone. It's created by default and hosted on TFS server.

You just need to change to your new created repo during the **connect** (click *plug* button).

[image]

After switching to the new created one, then clone it to the local.

You can also use `git clone [url]` command, how to get the new created repo's url, please refer this question [Connect to git repository in TFS or Visual Studio Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835212/connect-to-git-repository-in-tfs-or-visual-studio-online)

---

Update

- *How to create a new repo with using work item under your GIT team
  project.*

On the **Web Portal** - **Code** - Click the default repo(should be the same name with your team project)- **New repository**

[image]

After switching to the new created repo, you can see the corresponding url and clone your code to VS IDE. Then switching the repo in VS during your connection, you will get your local clone repository.

[image]

Comment: I can bind the repo to the local folder and use it via MSVS. But in this case I couldn`t work with work items of the project. So I can work or on the work items or on the repo - but not with both. How to work with both on one time?

Comment: I think you are messing up with some things. How did you create your new repo. With above way ( **Detail  please see my update**), you can still use the workitem of your GIT Team Project. Otherwise, you may have to create a new repo to achieve your need.