# How to get entire GIT repo url in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-2015

Only got a repo name and project name from my colleague.

How do I get the entire GIT repo url in TFS? What pattern does it follow?

Could I directly use the url in the browser from web?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you could directly use the url when you open the repo in the web portal.

A more common approach is using **Clone**  command in the top right corner. You should either select ***http*** or ***ssh*** url and just click copy command.

[image]

As for the format, the url will be something as below:

```
http://yourtfsserver/[CollectionName]/_git/[gitRepoName]
```

More details please take a look at the answer from *bryanmac* in this question:  [Connect to git repository in TFS or Visual Studio Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835212/connect-to-git-repository-in-tfs-or-visual-studio-online)